# Recycler view like instagram

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Can anyone please please help me
I want to create a recycler view with 1st row scrolling horizontally and the rest should be scrolling vertically just like instagram home page.
I have looked up almost everything but no luck.
Please can anyone help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post what you tried? else your question will be closed. Use different viewholders. For first item use the viewholder with RecyclerView (horizontal). For other items use normal viewholder

Comment: I tried doing that but the horizontal one stays at the top fixed.

Comment: then mention the problem what you faced. If you ask this kind of large question no one answer

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind .

Comment: Can you help me with this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter class

```
private static final int POSTER = 1; //for sliding item
private static final int CHILDGROUP = 2; //normal items
```

In getItemViewType()

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0 )
        return POSTER;
    else
        return CHILDGROUP;

}
```

In onCreateViewHolder() check which item & inflate layout as per item

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == POSTER) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listrow_auto_viewpager, parent, false);
        return new PosterSliderHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listrow_sub_category, parent, false);
        return new GroupViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

In onBindViewHolder() check the item type & load the data

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder.getItemViewType() == POSTER) {
    final PosterSliderHolder posterViewHolder = (PosterSliderHolder) holder;
    //your logic for sliding item (horizontal recyclerview )
    }
    else{
    final GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) holder;
     //normal list item
    }
 }
```

Comment: so you are asking me to put auto view pager for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: your choice. auto view pager or horizontal recyclerview as per your need. I give basic idea only

Comment: ok so i basically have to create two recycler views .in two activities and bind them up with same adapter is that so

Comment: In activity I use only one recyclerview with this adapter. code             HomeAdapter homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), "category");
            homeAdapter.updateList(adapterData, sliderImageData);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

Comment: what about models.did you create two models or only one.and what about the layouts you set in adapter

Comment: two models needed. create two layouts first one recyclerview or viewpager. second one normal list item. are you read my ans completely?

Comment: actualy i have to put card views inside vertical ones.So i was thinking that recycler view will be better rather than simple list view.

Comment: Please post your answer if you are able to achieve that @junaidshah